# Summary stats for missing values split by class

Tags: r, dataframe, summary

Here is my data frame:

```
x1 <- as.numeric(c(1.5, 3.2, 5.1, 6.6, NA))
x2 <- as.numeric(c(3.4, 5.6, NA, NA, 0.9))
x3 <- as.character(c("abc", NA, "cde", NA, NA))
x4 <- as.logical(c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0))
x5 <- as.integer(c(NA, 2, 4, 7, 9))

df <- data.frame(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Summary stats for missing values (percentages):

```
summary( round(apply(is.na(df), 2, sum)/(nrow(df)), 4) )
```

I could extract the columns by class and apply the summary stats 4 times to get these for the unique classes:

```
unique(sapply(df, class))
```

I was wondering if there is a nice way with fewer lines of code to put the summary stats in one table split by class?

I appreciate your help.

Thank you very much

Rami

Comment: Did you meant `lapply(split(seq_along(df), sapply(df, class)), function(x) summary(round(sum(is.na(df[x])/nrow(df),4))))`

Comment: Yes, thanks. But there's a typo in your code ;-) `lapply(split(seq_along(df), sapply(df, class)), function(x) summary(round(apply(is.na(df[x]), 2, sum)/(nrow(df)), 4)))`

Comment: If that is the output you wanted, we can use `colMeans` (posted as an answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We `split` the sequence of columns by the 'class' of each column to get a `list`, subset the dataset, convert to logical matrix (`is.na(df[x])`), get the column means (`colMeans`), `round` (if necessary) and do the `summary`.

```
lapply(split(seq_along(df), sapply(df, class)), 
   function(x) summary(round(colMeans(is.na(df[x])),4)))
```